# Change 'error' class in clientside validation module

Tags: 7

I am working on drupal 7 clientside validation module.On validation which displays error messages with 'error' class which is same as  drupal's system error message's class.But I want seperate theming for clientside validation so I want to change the class 'error' to 'newerror' without hacking the module.I searched everything in web but most suggestions for altering error messages.I dont want to change systems error class.Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for clientside validation module and should be posted in module's issue queue. Only module maintainer can change it's code in a way that will not count as "hacking".

Comment: @Mołot Thanks for your quick reply.I posted in modules issue queue.Just asked hoping someone is done with it.